# operador "|" (tubería) para enlazar aplicaciones

Tags: java

En una tarea debo utilizar el operador "|" (tubería) de forma que el resultado de *aleatoriosNumeros* sea la entrada para *ordenarNumeros*.

```
public class aleatoriosNumeros {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int aleatorio = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; ++i){
            aleatorio = (int) (Math.random()*100);
            System.out.println(aleatorio);
        }
    }
    
}

public class ordenarNumeros {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Introduzca el total de numeros que desea ingresar: ");
        int totNum = sc.nextInt();
        int[] num = new int[totNum];
        System.out.println("Introduzca " + totNum + " numero(s): ");
        for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
        System.out.print("Numero " + (i+1) + ": ");
        num[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
                
        Arrays.sort(num);
        
        System.out.println("\nLos numeros ingresados ORDENADOS ASCENDENTEMENTE son: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
        System.out.println(num[i]);
        }
    }
    
}
```

Estoy utilizando comunicaciones con sockets pero no entiendo donde debo utilizar dicho operador "|". Lo mismo estoy complicándome y es algo mucho mas sencillo y una cosa no tiene nada que ver con la otra.

¿Podríais decirme como se podría hacer ese "enlace" entre aplicaciones con dicho operador?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: En Java no existe tal "operador tubería".

Comment: Te sugiero agregues más información , a que te refieres con enlazar?

Comment: A ver, de primeras he entendido mal el ejercicio. Mis disculpas. El ejercicio consiste en utilizar dicho operador desde CMD para enlazar ambas aplicaciones. Básicamente es comunicación entre procesos (sockets o tuberías). Voy a ver si avanzo ahora que tengo otra perspectiva de éste.

Comment: Yo , estoy igual, creo que es el mismo ejercicio. mira este video de youtube espero que no tenga problemas por colgar el enlace https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ToGRiaIZip4 Un saludo y espero que te sirva de ayuda